# Spring Cloud Config - Serving multiple applications which has multiple configuration files

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Currently we are planning to externalize configurations related to multiple our applications with the help of Spring Cloud Config. But we are having an issue because for some of applications, we are maintaining multiple configuration files like below

```
application-a
  - abc-config.yml
  - bca-config.yml
  - cab-config.yml

application-b
  - xyz-config.yml
  - yzx-config.yml
  - zxy-config.yml
```

We know that multiple files can be loaded by a client application by defining `spring.cloud.config.name` like below but it restricts to a single application

```
spring.cloud.config.name=abc-config,bca-config,cab-config
```

So far the best solution we found is using the pattern matching feature with renaming each config file related to each application with a prefix or suffix to identify each application like below

```
application-a
  - app-a-abc-config.yml
  - app-a-bca-config.yml
  - app-a-cab-config.yml

application-b
  - app-b-xyz-config.yml
  - app-b-yzx-config.yml
  - app-b-zxy-config.yml
```

Then based on the pattern check we use different git repos for different application like below

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/sample/common-repo
          repos:
            application-a:
              pattern:
                - '*app-a*'
              uri: https://github.com/sample/app-a-repo
            application-b:
              pattern:
                - '*app-b*'
              uri: https://github.com/sample/app-b-repo
```

We need to know whether is there any other cleaner (without renaming config files) and easier way to do this. May be a solution provided by Spring Cloud Config itself for a scenario like this.

Comment: Have you tried placeholders `{application}` https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_placeholders_in_git_uri

Comment: @spencergibb I guess that can be used to support one repo for one application? But how expose several configuration files under each that application?

Comment: You can try multiple profiles

Comment: Did you come up with a clean solution for this?